# Is it possible to have the same source code under 2 version control?

Tags: svn, accurev

In our team,we are  using Accurev as SCM and we have local SVN setup also.Just we want to do all modifications then  checkin to SVN then  build and test our code.If everything works fine,i will Promote the same code to Accurev .Here the Accurev Server is at client location ,so i want to double check my code before promoting it in to Accurev where client will have a look in to my code.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Answer (score 1):

In a normal setup, you'd want to create a development/feature branch off the main trunk (in client's Accurev). This dev/feature branch can be "tested" with automated or manual builds, and when you feel it is good enough, then you merge it to the main trunk.

If your criteria is that the client absolutely does not see any of your work-in-progress. Then by all means, you need to separate that, but now the onus is on you to keep everything in sync.

I am however failing to see the actual question. Is it possible? Of course, you can copy-paste anything as many times as you want. Are you looking for a technical solution to have a single local workspace be managed by multiple SCMs? If so, that is **really not a good idea**.

You would need to tell each SCM to exclude the "inner workings files" of the other SCM. Don't know anything about Accurev, but all SVN related configuration in the workspace is saved in local `.svn` folders. If would have to tell Accurev to exclude `.svn` folders. Similarly, you can tell SVN to "ignore" certain files from commits. I don't know what Accurev uses to store it's configuration on local filesystem.

Comment: accurev stores its files in a `.accurev` folder and you can add it to your ignore list. Accurev's ignore files are called `.acignore` IIRC...

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this.  A source code management ought to a source of truth.  You can't say that if you have two.  You only need one.

What you want to do is easy with Git.  You have one master repository and as many local versions as you'd like.

Why can't you simply give your client access to your repository, a la Github?

It sounds to me like this is a simple problem with a simple, existing solution.

Comment: While Git may be a great solution, there may be costs involved (private repositories) or the client may say "no, we like what we have."

Comment: Terrific - what's your suggestion, then?

Comment: You can certainly approach the client and ask (re: git), the other options are to use only their system or to do as you ask about. It is certainly possible to do what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Do you just sit on the sidelines and comment or do you actually answer questions here?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, using multiple SCM systems is possible and you can probably script movement of code between the systems, but to be perfectly clear, this is a bad idea.

AccuRev has stream and depot ACLs that you can protect specific streams from groups (or individual) of users, allowing you to protect your test streams. Combine that with locks that can block promotion and changing of the stream attributes themselves, you have a fairly secure setup as long as this is supported by the server_admin_trig trigger.